# Run cleanmgr on x64 from 32bits app in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, manifest

My main app is a win32 app, run as admin (UAC is prompted whan launched).

I need to run cleanmgr.

I use `createprocess` to launch cleanmgr.

```
 GetStartupInfo(stinfo);
  stinfo.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  CreateProcess(nil,PChar(ExpandEnvironment('%systemroot%') + '\System32\cleanmgr.exe  /sagerun:3'),nil,nil, False,DETACHED_PROCESS,  nil,PChar(ExpandEnvironment('%systemroot%')),stinfo,procinf);
```

It works on XP 32bits but not on Win7 64bits.
Cleanmgr is configured via `cleanmgr.exe /sageset:3` to clean up recycle bin.

When using `CreateProcess` as shown above, 
recycle bin is emptied on XP but not on Win7.

I see `cleanmgr` running 
but it has no effect on recycle bin.

Why ?

Comment: Show how you create the other process.

Comment: CreateProcess(nil,PChar(ExpandEnvironment('%systemroot%') + '\System32\cleanmgr.exe  /sagerun:3'),nil,nil, False,DETACHED_PROCESS,  nil,PChar(ExpandEnvironment('%systemroot%')),stinfo,procinf);

Comment: This information should be in the question. Please add via an edit.

Comment: I modified the entire question after further investigation.

Comment: Hmm, that question looks a bit different. Could you describe the failure mode on Win7.

Comment: Is it down to there being a different token in play. Perhaps what you need is for cleanmgr to run non-elevated. If your app runs elevated then so will any processes that it starts. Try running your app asInvoker to test out that hypothesis.

Comment: Also, you talk about /sageset:3 and /sagerun:3, which should it be? Are you running same code on both platforms?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look here :
http://community.kaseya.com/xsp/f/28/p/12610/62060.aspx

Comment: I have Win7 x64 and my app is 32bits